# Which caption to use in a <figure> tag in HTML5?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, figure

I read this question: [Do I still need to use the title attribute if my element has a `<figcaption>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799285/do-i-still-need-to-use-the-title-attribute-if-my-element-has-a-figcaption)

But the answer is oriented to `img` tag, but, if I have the following `figure`, without a `img`, but with a `table`:

```
<figure title="The table of life">
  <table>
    <caption>The table of life</caption>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
  </table>
  <figcaption>The table of life<figcaption>
</figure>
```

Here I have 3 ways to give a caption: the `<caption>` tag (only for `table`), the `<figcaption>` tag (only for `figure`) and the `title` attribute (generic).

Which one is better to use?

Here is an example of `figure` without `table`:

```
<figure title="Description of my char in RPG">
  <h1>Seninha</h1>
  <p>Seninha was born in the moon in the year of 13...<p>
  <dl>
    <dt>HP</dt><dd>15</dd>
    <dt>MP</dt><dd>18</dd>
    <dt>IQ</dt><dd>99999</dd>
    <dt>ST</dt><dd>-10</dd>
  </dl>
  <figcaption>Description of my char in RPG<figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 3):

`caption` is only valid as a child of `table`. [The MDN docs for `caption` note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption):

> Usage note: When the `<table>` element that is the parent of this
>   `<caption>` is the only descendant of a `<figure>` element, use the
>   `<figcaption>` element instead.

I'd leave out the `title` attribute as it doesn't contribute anything.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 (CR) spec [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/tabular-data.html#the-caption-element):

> When a `table` element is the only content in a `figure` element other than the `figcaption`, the `caption` element should be omitted in favor of the `figcaption`.

So you should use `figcaption` but no `caption`:

```
<figure>
  <table>
    <tbody>…</tbody>
  </table>
  <figcaption>The table of life<figcaption>
</figure>
```

---

You should not rely on the [`title` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/dom.html#the-title-attribute) if used on `table`, and information should never be duplicated in the `title`, so that means that you should *not* use the `title` attribute *instead* of `figcaption`, and if you want to give a `title`, it should not contain the same content as the `figcaption`.

Comment: So the best way to use caption in a block of content (table, img, paragraph, etc) is figcaption?

My intent is to show a comment for a paragraph or a group of paragraph using `figure+figcaption` or `title` attribute in my personal website. I used `title`and here is the result (in portuguese) http://seninha.net

I can do it with `figcaption`, but the markup will be correct?

Comment: @Seninha: Why are you using `figure` in the first place? It seems that it’s not needed in your example. Anyway, using the `title` attribute is not a good choice for providing a title for `figure`, unless this title is not important for understanding the content.